# Does autocomplete's select event block limit scope?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am developing a tags solution (check jsfiddle below) and as soon as you start typing in the text box, autocomplete kicks in and retrieves the available tags from an array (for demonstration purposes only)

The problem comes after selecting the tag from the autocomplete drop down because once the desired tag is selected, jQuery is not cleaning my textbox.

I created a fiddle for you to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/TQCzd/

The relevant lines are 51-59:

```
            $('<input type="text" value="" name="tagName" id="tagName" placeholder="Start typing tag name" class="new_tag_input" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }" />')
                .autocomplete({
                    source: "/get_tags_autocomplete",
                    minLength:1,
                    select: function(e, ui) {
                        $this.addTag(ui.item.label);
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                })
```

The following line:

`$(this).val('');`

supposedly should be cleaning the textbox, but it doesn't do it within autocomplete's `select` event block.

I've tried it all, and I haven't been able to clear the textbox **after** selecting an option from the drop down.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

add this next to "success" function and it will work :)

```
close: function(e, ui){ this.value = ''; }
```

Comment: Awesome! How come it works with the close event, but not once the select event is done?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have so much knowledge about that widget - i can only assume that $(this) in search method refers to widget itself and close() is fired up in different scope (input field) after widget is destroyed

Comment: It does work, however if do not select an option from the autocomplete's drop down it will erase after closing the drop down (naturally because it's inside the close event block). 

I tried this.value =''; inside the select event block, didn't work :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DdJYD/ I know it's not perfect solution, but still... on open() you set variable changed to false, on select you change that to true (withdraw from choosing will not change that cause select() won't fire) - that way in close You could check if someone really choose one of values from autocomplete - like I said it's quick and dirty